# Alloy Rest Sync create model error

Tags: backbone.js, titanium, synchronization, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Cannot create a new model using alloy sync adapter.
This is my model

```
exports.definition = {  
        config: {
            "URL": "http://localhost:8888/appname/web/app_dev.php/api/dreams",
            "debug": 1, 
            "adapter": {
                "type": "restapi",
                "collection_name": "dream",
                "idAttribute": "id",
            },
        },      
        extendModel: function(Model) {_.extend(Model.prototype, {});
            return Model;
        },  
        extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
            _.extend(Collection.prototype, {});
            return Collection;
        }       
};
```

and this is my controller function

```
var dream = Alloy.createModel('dream', { title: 'Ubik', body: 'Philip K. Dick', user: '2', image: 'dsaf' });

dream.save();
```

I get this error

```
[ERROR] :  No request object found. Did you call open?
[ERROR] :  No request object found. Did you call open?
[ERROR] :  No request object found. Did you call open?
[ERROR] :  [REST API] CREATE ERROR:
[ERROR] :  {
[ERROR] :      code = 500;
[ERROR] :      error = "HTTP error";
[ERROR] :      responseJSON =     {
[ERROR] :          errors =         {
[ERROR] :              errors =             (
[ERROR] :              );
[ERROR] :              form =             {
[ERROR] :                  children =                 {
[ERROR] :                      body =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      image =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      title =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      user =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                  };
[ERROR] :              };
[ERROR] :          };
[ERROR] :      };
[ERROR] :      responseText = "{\"errors\":{\"form\":{\"children\":{\"title\":[],\"image\":[],\"body\":[],\"user\":[]}},\"errors\":[]}}";
[ERROR] :      status = error;
[ERROR] :      success = 0;
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR: {"errors":{"form":{"children":{"title":[],"image":[],"body":[],"user":[]}},"errors":[]}}
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR CODE: 500
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR MSG: HTTP error
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR URL: http://localhost:8888/appname/web/app_dev.php/api/dreams
[ERROR] :  [REST API] CREATE ERROR:
[ERROR] :  {
[ERROR] :      code = 500;
[ERROR] :      error = "HTTP error";
[ERROR] :      responseJSON =     {
[ERROR] :          errors =         {
[ERROR] :              errors =             (
[ERROR] :              );
[ERROR] :              form =             {
[ERROR] :                  children =                 {
[ERROR] :                      body =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      image =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      title =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      user =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                  };
[ERROR] :              };
[ERROR] :          };
[ERROR] :      };
[ERROR] :      responseText = "{\"errors\":{\"form\":{\"children\":{\"title\":[],\"image\":[],\"body\":[],\"user\":[]}},\"errors\":[]}}";
[ERROR] :      status = error;
[ERROR] :      success = 0;
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR: {"errors":{"form":{"children":{"title":[],"image":[],"body":[],"user":[]}},"errors":[]}}
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR CODE: 500
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR MSG: HTTP error
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR URL: http://localhost:8888/appname/web/app_dev.php/api/dreams
[ERROR] :  [REST API] CREATE ERROR:
[ERROR] :  {
[ERROR] :      code = 500;
[ERROR] :      error = "HTTP error";
[ERROR] :      responseJSON =     {
[ERROR] :          errors =         {
[ERROR] :              errors =             (
[ERROR] :              );
[ERROR] :              form =             {
[ERROR] :                  children =                 {
[ERROR] :                      body =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      image =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      title =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                      user =                     (
[ERROR] :                      );
[ERROR] :                  };
[ERROR] :              };
[ERROR] :          };
[ERROR] :      };
[ERROR] :      responseText = "{\"errors\":{\"form\":{\"children\":{\"title\":[],\"image\":[],\"body\":[],\"user\":[]}},\"errors\":[]}}";
[ERROR] :      status = error;
[ERROR] :      success = 0;
[ERROR] :  }
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR: {"errors":{"form":{"children":{"title":[],"image":[],"body":[],"user":[]}},"errors":[]}}
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR CODE: 500
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR MSG: HTTP error
[ERROR] :  [REST API] apiCall ERROR URL: 

http://localhost:8888/appname/web/app_dev.php/api/dreams
```

**Further Info**

I am using this adapter
 https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi

I can edit,get,getall model(s).. I'm only stuck at the create model and I have no clue what's going wrong.. I tried testing my api itself using Advanced Rest Client and it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess. I use the same restapi adapter - and it seems to work fine for my use cases.

Normally, an http error "500" means that something on the server side went wrong. So you may want to trace this problem on the server side first.

I use Google's Postman REST Client (can be found under Google Chrome Apps - in the bookmark bar) to test all REST calls. This way I can separate things and verify the that the server is working as I expect it prior to trying to use the service in my apps :-)

/John

Comment: Thanks, it might be the problem. I'll test it using Googles postman, on a side note can you provide me with any documentation to using this restapi adapter as the documentation found is very minimal. Thanks again for your help

Comment: No, I don't have any more documentation than you can find in the Git Repo. What you do seems Ok. I really believe that your problem is related to the service on the server - it may require something else than you are providing.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration once again, I did use postman and the server side works with the following request 

POST /appname/web/app_dev.php/api/dreams HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

title=image&image=body&body=aslkdfja&user=2

I don't know if this request is different from the one sent by the restapi adapter. if you have any clue on how can I fix this I'd be glad @JohnDalsgaard

Comment: Did you find any solution to it? I am facing the same issue. :(
It works fine on Android, but not on iPhone.